# lgrep and rgrep in Emacs

Tags: emacs, grep

I am having problems with the greps in Emacs.

a) grep doesnt seem to understand the .[ch] for searching .c and .h files. This is a default option provided by Emacs with the **lgrep** command. The example is searching for the word "global" in .c/.h files.

```
grep -i -nH "global" *.[ch]
grep: *.[ch]: No such file or directory

Grep exited abnormally with code 2 at Mon Feb 16 19:34:36
```

Is this format not valid?

b) Using **rgrep** I get the following error:

```
find . "(" -path "*/CVS" -o -path "*/.svn" -o -path "*/{arch}" -o -path "*/.hg" -o -path "*/_darcs" -o -path "*/.git" -o -path "*/.bzr" ")" -prune -o  -type f "(" -iname "*.[ch]" ")" -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep -i -nH "global"
FIND: Wrong parameter format

Grep finished (matches found) at Mon Feb 16 19:37:10
```

I am using Emacs 22.3.1 on Windows XP with the GNU W32 Utils (grep, find, xargs etc.). Grep v2.5.3 and find v4.2.20.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

Too bad one can't accept multiple answers...since the solution to my problems are spread out.

```
grep -i -nH "global" *.c *.h
```

This solves the first problem. Thanks luapyad!

```
(setq find-program "c:\\path\\to\\gnuw32\\find.exe")
```

emacs was indeed using the Windows find.exe. Forcing the gnu32 find fixed the second problem. Thanks scottfrazer.

However, I still like [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/) best.

Comment: A simpler way to use rgrep is: grep -r --include=\*.[ch] --exclude=\*/{CVS,.svn,arch,.hg,_darcs,.git,.bzr} -i -nH global .

Comment: Could you change your post to accurately reflect the answer for find-program? You caused me some difficulty today. The difference is the need for double back-slashes.
(setq find-program "C:\\path\\to\\gnuw32\\find.exe")

Comment: @Matthew Talbert, I think that the markdown processor was swallowing the extra backslashes. I submitted an edit to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is always [Ack](http://petdance.com/ack/) and [Ack.el](http://repo.or.cz/w/ShellArchive.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=ack.el)

Comment: Doh! I totally forgot about Ack! Love it in Vim. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I found out that using:

```
(setq find-program "\"C:/path/to/GnuWin32/bin/find.exe\"")
(setq grep-program "\"C:/path/to/GnuWin32/bin/grep.exe\"")
```

Works better in windows, since you could have a space laying around the path and will screw up eventually.

Notice I used the two programs in my `.emacs` file.

Hope it's of some help to some other programmer in need ;)

Answer (score 5):

For a) it looks like there are simply no .c or .h files in the current directory.

For b) Windows is trying to use its own find instead of the one from the GNU W32 Utils.  Try:

`(setq find-program "c:\\path\\to\\gnuw32\\find.exe")`

Answer (score 4):

Adam Rosenfield comment is worth expanding into an answer:

```
grep -r --include=\*.[ch] --exclude=\*{CVS,.svn,arch} -i -nH
```

To make the example given in this question work, use this:

```
grep -i -nH --include=\*.[ch] "global" *
```

It is also helpful to set the variable `grep-command` providing defaults to `M-x grep`:

```
(setq grep-command "grep -i -nH --include=\*.[ch] ")
```

Also here are some other useful command line parameters to grep:

```
-n print the line number

-s suppress error messages

-r recursive
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the general problem is the windows cmd "shell" behaves very differently to a unix shell in respect to filename expansion regexps and wildcards.

To answer your (a) above try using:

```
grep -i -nH "global" *.c *.h
```

(You will still get an "invalid argument" if no *.c's or *.h's exist).

Or you can use command line option `--include=\*.[ch]` to make windows grep do "proper" filename pattern matching (see `grep --help` for other options)

Answer (score 1):

I usually just use `M-x grep` and alter the command line args when prompted if I need to.  But I just tried running `M-x lgrep` and got the same thing as you.  It simply means that no files match `*.[ch]` in the current directory.  You can customize the default options to include `-r` and search recursively through child directories as well:

```
M-x customize-group RET grep RET
```

Search for lgrep in that buffer to find/edit the Grep Template.

As far as `M-x rgrep` goes, I suspect it has something to do with the Windows version of `find` not liking the default options.  That command works fine for me on Linux.  Search for rgrep in that same customize buffer and tweak those options until the Windows find is happy.

Sorry I can't be more help with the Windows options, but I'm not familiar with them.